# ASP.NET unable to add a reference

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace SC.BL.Domain
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the WebApp1User class
    public class WebApp1User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }

    }

    public enum UserStatus
    {
        Submitted,
        Approved,
        Rejected
    }
}
```

It can't find AspNetCore in the reference: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
See image for more details [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZFrd.png)

Comment: Which version of Asp.net Core are you using?

Comment: Can you show project file to check the references?

Comment: Are you sure this is even ASP.NET Core MVC? Have you added a reference to Identity?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `PackageReference` to `YourProject.csproj` file and rebuild. Problem should go away because this meta package contain all the necessary packages for ASP.NET Core MVC, Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core Identity for **ASP.NET Core Version <= 2.2**

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    .......
 </ItemGroup>
```